# pandas df: add column if doesn't exist, add values to new column from dict

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am new to pandas but I'm trying to create a large dataframe where I organize information about lots of sequences by their sequence IDs (Seq_ID) and add information about the sequences to the dataframe. 
Currently the df looks something like this:

```
     Seq_ID        mol_type
0 4_cDNA_v              RNA
1 2_133+_v              RNA
2 5_BM4D_g              RNA
.                         .
.                         .
1301 4_PB_g             RNA
```

I want to write a function that looks at my current df, source_df, and if the column 'Seq_source' does not exist, it adds it. 
Then to fill in the column 'Seq_Source', I have a series of key:value pairs called cell_type. I want to search the Seq_ID column to see if any of the values are found in the Seq_ID, and if so, add the key in its corresponding row in the new column, 'Seq_Source' so that it looks like the following:

```
     Seq_ID    mol_type    Seq_Source
0 4_cDNA_v          RNA            PB
1 2_133+_v          RNA          HSPC
2 5_BM4D_g          RNA          BMMC
.                     
.                     
1301 4_CD4_g        RNA          PBMC
```

I wrote some pseudocode to help explain my thinking about an approach.

```
cell_type = {
    'PBMC':['CD4','NK', 'CD8'],
    'HSPC': ['133+', '133+F'],
    'PB': ['cDNA', 'cDNAA', 'cDNAB', 'cDNAC'],
    'BMMC':['cDNABM', '34D_Vc','BM4_Vs', 'BM4_Vc', 'BM4n_Vs']
        }


def find_cell_source(dictionary, df, reference, new_header):
    '''
    takes in a dictionary where key corresponds to list of values.
    If new_header does not exist, the new column is created.
    If a value from key:value pair is found within any of the string entries under reference column
    in the database, key is added to reference row under new_header.
    '''

    # add new_header if does not exist
    df[new_header] = [df[new_header] if new_header not in df]

    # read rows of reference column and see if values from dict is in references
    # add key to row under new_header if it exists, pass if it doesn't

    for i in df['reference']:
        for k,v in dictionary:
            for j in v:
                if j in i:
                    df['new_header'] = k
                else:
                    pass
    return df


find_cell_source(cell_type, source_df, 'Seq_ID', 'Seq_Source')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can grab the relevant part of `Seq_ID` in various ways, in this case it seems like you can just use `.str.split`, and then map the values. Perhaps use `regex` if splitting on `_` is not enough

```
d = dict((k,v) for v, x in cell_type.items() for k in x)
df['Seq_Source'] = df.Seq_ID.str.split('_', expand=True)[1].map(d)
```

Output:

```
        Seq_ID mol_type Seq_Source
0     4_cDNA_v      RNA         PB
1     2_133+_v      RNA       HSPC
2     5_BM4D_g      RNA        NaN
1301   4_CD4_g      RNA       PBMC
```

Note that since `BM4D` is not in any of the lists in `cell_type` it gets mapped to `NaN`

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you find yourself frequently having to lookup a value to recover a key, it is usually best to reshape that dictionary to allow you to lookup by key, which is more efficient.

Assuming all of the values in the inner lists are unique, you can reshape your lookup dictionary using the following snippet:

```
cell_type_reshaped = {}

for k, v in cell_type.items():
    for element in v:
        cell_type_reshaped[element] = k
```

Giving:

```
{'133+': 'HSPC',
 '133+F': 'HSPC',
 '34D_Vc': 'BMMC',
 'BM4_Vc': 'BMMC',
 'BM4_Vs': 'BMMC',
 'BM4n_Vs': 'BMMC',
 'CD4': 'PBMC',
 'CD8': 'PBMC',
 'NK': 'PBMC',
 'cDNA': 'PB',
 'cDNAA': 'PB',
 'cDNAB': 'PB',
 'cDNABM': 'BMMC',
 'cDNAC': 'PB'}
```

Creating a small DataFrame to test on:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['4_cDNA_v', 'RNA'], ['2_133+_v', 'RNA'], 
                        ['5_BM4D_g', 'RNA']], columns=['Seq_ID', 'mol_type'])
```

From here, it's simply a case of looking up the dictionary using the Pandas map function. Note that there's an additional step here which slices your Seq_ID to get the 3rd to 3rd from last characters of the string inclusive, which seems to be the pattern they follow. If this is not the case please let me know and I can update.

```
df['Seq_Source'] = df['Seq_ID'].str.slice(2, -2).map(cell_type_reshaped)
```

Giving what I believe is at least close to your desired result:

```
     Seq_ID mol_type Seq_Source
0  4_cDNA_v      RNA         PB
1  2_133+_v      RNA       HSPC
2  5_BM4D_g      RNA        NaN
```

In your example I see you have 5_BM4D_g mapping to BMMC, I wasn't sure of the logic behind this so please comment and I can update.

Comment: You caught my mistake with 5_BM4D_g mapping to BMMC...I paired down the number of items in the list of values for BMMC to make the list shorter for posting, but in my longer list of values, BM4D should map to BMMC.

Comment: Also, for the key:value arrangement, I wasn't sure if I should re-structure the dict the way you clearly have. I'm happy to know this is the more efficient way to structure the dict. Thanks!